# PHP: use regex for get contain data not work

Tags: php, html, regex, web-scraping, preg-match-all

My code:

```
$data = '<div class="overlay">
                            <p>
            <a href="/name/nm0136797/?ref_=nv_cel_dflt_2" id="nameAdClick">
                                    <strong>Steve Carell</strong>
                                </a> »
                                <br>
                                #<strong>228</strong> on STARmeter
                            </p>
                        </div>'
```

Regex :

```
<a href="/name/.*/\?ref_=nv_cel_dflt_2".*>(.*)<\/a>
```

But not return any thing

This code some times work and some times not work!

Link for test : https://regex101.com/r/snYqoC/1

Comment: I advise against using regex to parse valid html to reduce the chances of "some times not work".  Please show your _actual_ `preg_` function calling code.  Are you using pattern delimiters?

Comment: Are you able to rely on the `id="nameAdClick"` attribute instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As regex101.com says on the reporting error as soon as you enter the link you have posted, a catastrophic error occurs [see here](https://regex101.com/r/snYqoC/5)(due to the checking of the ".*" after the "name/" literal probably capturing every symbol and thus making it fail).

I have tried fixing this by defining the characters of the regex to match as the name only to be letters from A to z and numbers from 0 to 9 and finds one match inside the text (if there is more or require some other specific characters, i suggest to specify them in the same group).

regex goes like this:

```
<a href="/name/([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9])*/\?ref_=nv_cel_dflt_2".*>(.*)<\/a>
```

link for the test results [here](https://regex101.com/r/snYqoC/5)

hope it works for you

Comment: `[A-z]|[0-9]` this is not refined regex and the OP does not want to capture that substring either.

Comment: agreeing with @mickmackusa, sorry for the non-refined option (still a few programs required me of using regex, not very used to it) but for certain an Xpath alternative should be a better idea

Comment: Really thankful for the feedback @Toto i will take this info for further solutions on my regex (i had no idea, never checked up :c) 
Also, I have corrected the solution to prevent that

Comment: `[A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]` is strictly the same that `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use negated characters classes instead of "any character" dots to match.

`~<a href="/name/[^/]*/\?ref_=nv_cel_dflt_2"[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*</a>~is`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/snYqoC/4)

I'll add a DomDocument / Xpath alternative as soon as I can.

Comment: reporting for .* is correct. @Pablo Alvarez answer is correct for me. than you

Comment: There are always _many_ correct regex patterns, but the difference is in the accuracy, efficiency, brevity, and readability.

Comment: Thank you. i use your code. in regex101 work fine, but in php not work and return empty array : `preg_match_all('~<a href="/name/[^/]*?/\?ref_=tt_ov_dr">(.*)<\/a>~isU', $data, $return);
        print_r($return);`

Comment: remove the `U`.  and I should have removed the `?` after `[^/]*`.  Are you quoting your pattern with `'` or with `"`?

Comment: what is the url that you are scraping?  I'd like to write up the domdocument equivalent for my answer.

Comment: ...well, I tried to use DomDocument on your RegexDemo sample text, but there must be something invalid in the html because it won't parse.  I can only possibly show a DomDocument approach if you provide the url that you are scraping.